# Adding data to DOM on submit with pure JS

Tags: javascript, html, dom, submit, frontend

Can someone tell me what the best way to achieve the same thing seen [here](http://codepen.io/SusanneLundblad/pen/tGizK) with this js:

```
function ContactController($scope) {
   $scope.contacts = ["hi@me.no", "hi@you.com"];
    $scope.addMail = function() {
        if(this.mailAdress) {
          $scope.contacts.push($scope.mailAdress);
          $scope.mailAdress = "";
        }
      };
    }
```

without the use of Angular.  I am just trying to learn how save user input to the DOM using javascript.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing the same is

```
  var contacts = ["hi@me.no", "hi@you.com"],
        ul = document.querySelectorAll('.email-list')[0];

  // Iterate over the contacts and append it to the ul
  for (var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
    addEmailToContacts(contacts[i]);
  }

  function addEmailToContacts(contact) {
      var li = document.createElement('li');
      li.innerHTML = contact;

      ul.appendChild(li);
  };

  // Click event for the submit
  document.querySelector('#submit').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // Get the value
    var value = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="mail"]')[0].value;
    if (value) {
      addEmailToContacts(value);
    }
  })
```

**[Check Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YqXVde)**

Answer (score 1):

You can use `form` element, `input type="email"` element with `required` attribute, `onsubmit` event, `event.preventDefault()`, `Array.prototype.push()` , `Array.prototype.forEach()`, `.innerHTML`

```js
var contacts = ["hi@me.no", "hi@you.com"],
  div = document.getElementById("update");

function updateContacts() {
  div.innerHTML = "";
  contacts.forEach(function(address) {
    div.innerHTML += address + "<br>"
  })
}

updateContacts();

document.forms[0].onsubmit = function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  // user input to update `contacts` array
  contacts.push(this["input"].value);
  // display updated `contacts` array      
  updateContacts();
}
```

```html
<div id="update">
</div>

<form>
  <input name="input" type="email" required />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: I understand this.  I was wondering how you would append user input to the contact list on submit.

Comment: See lines 3 and 4 at post

Comment: This does not gather the user's input on submit?